# Computing the ChiSquare

Tags: vba, excel, chi-squared

I am writing a user-defined function in excel vba. So this new function:

1. takes 4 input value
2. some calculation to generate into 8 numbers. ( 2 arrays - each array has 4 numbers)
3. do a chisquare test
4. return 1 output value

Code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim A, B, C, D As Variant
    A = 33
    B = 710
    C = 54
    D = 656

    'Observed Value
    Dim O_A As Variant
    Dim O_B As Variant
    Dim O_V As Variant
    Dim O_D As Variant

    'Define Observer Value
    O_C_A = 'Some Calucation'
    O_C_B = 'Some Calucation'
    O_T_C = 'Some Calucation'
    O_T_C = 'Some Calucation'

    'Expected Value
    Dim E_C_A As Variant
    Dim E_C_B As Variant
    Dim E_T_C As Variant
    Dim E_T_D As Variant

    'Define Expected Value
    E_C_A = 'Some Calucation'
    E_C_B = 'Some Calucation'
    E_T_C = 'Some Calucation'
    E_T_D = 'Some Calucation'

    'Create array(2x2)
    Dim Chi_square_result As Variant

    Dim my_array(1, 1)
    my_array(0, 0) = O_C_Mesaurement
    my_array(0, 1) = O_C_Balance
    my_array(1, 0) = O_T_Measurement
    my_array(1, 1) = O_T_Balance

    Dim my_array2(1, 1)
    my_array2(0, 0) = E_C_Mesaurement
    my_array2(0, 1) = E_C_Balance
    my_array2(1, 0) = E_T_Measurement
    my_array2(1, 1) = E_T_Balance

    'Create a chi square test formula'
    Dim formula(1 To 5) As String
    formula(1) = "CHITEST("
    formula(2) = my_array
    formula(3) = ","
    formula(4) = my_array2
    formula(5) = ")"

    'Chi Square
    Chi_square_result = evaluate(Join(formula, ""))
end sub
```

It gives a runtime error '13', saving type mismatch. This is because of the concatenation of the formula.

Comment: Which line do you receive this error?

Comment: Try it as `Chi_square_result = Application.Chitest(my_array1, my_array2)`

Comment: `formula(2) = my_array1` should be `formula(2) = my_array`?

Comment: This line - > formula(2) = my_array1

Comment: You do not have a `my_array1`. You have `my_array`

Comment: Siddharth, please ignore this. just a typo. i was trying other method to solve this.

Comment: You cannot stuff a variant array into a single array element of a string array.

Comment: I tried changing that array into a string array. still the same error.
Or am i misunderstanding it?

I tried the Chi_square_result = Application.Chitest(my_array, my_array2) . It returns 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evaluate is expecting worksheet cell ranges. Use the [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx) or [WorksheetFunction object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx) to compute the function within VBA.

This proofs out.

```
Dim dbl As Double
Dim my_array1(1, 1)
my_array1(0, 0) = 1
my_array1(0, 1) = 2
my_array1(1, 0) = 3
my_array1(1, 1) = 4

Dim my_array2(1, 1)
my_array2(0, 0) = 2
my_array2(0, 1) = 3
my_array2(1, 0) = 4
my_array2(1, 1) = 5

dbl = Application.ChiTest(my_array1, my_array2)
Debug.Print dbl
```

Result from the VBE's Immediate window: `0.257280177154182`.

Comment: Jeeped, thanks. I use this in immediate window and it works. However, using the same method have the 'Public Function chi_square_2() As Integer' and have the 'chi_square_2 = Application.ChiTest(my_array1, my_array2)'

It returns 0. I am not familiar with VBA so I am not sure what i did wrong

Comment: I cannot test fully as you've provided no sample data nor expected results but `0.257280177154182` is not an integer, it is a double.

Comment: oh, nevermind. I had a typo. That's greatlearning something new about Application object and evalute :) thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing a function, you have your format wrong.

```
Function Chi_square_result(A as Long, B as Long, C as Long, D as Long) as Double
    'All your manipulations here

    Chi_square_result = (Your math equation)

End Function
```

You also never defined my_array1, I am assuming it is supposed to be where you typed 'my_array'. I also do not think Join is your best bet. You are trying to do an awful lot of array manipulation, and I think your dimensions are getting you. It would be better to do it in a more straight forward way.

Comment: Hi SandPiper, what would be more straight forward way? I think the problem i have is turning all the values i have into array because Chisquare function only takes 2 arrays as input.

Comment: I was not familiar with it, so I looked up CHITEST(). It is a worksheet function, so the way to access it in VBA would be Application.WorksheetFunction.ChiTest(Range1, Range2). It is expecting a range, and I do not know of a way to pass that function anything other than a range. That is likely why you are getting an error.

Comment: Also, your line where you Dim out your observed variables has different variable names than the defined observed variables right below it. Then, in your arrays you are not using any of these variables but instead inserting brand new ones into the elements.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reason to do this task in VBA instead of on a spreadsheet? If you really need it in VBA, there are a few ways to do it. You can do the calculation on a worksheet with a cell formula then refer to that cell value in VBA. Or, you can look up what that chi test formula is and retype it in VBA using the values you have.

Comment: Just need to create a new function that has chi square as part of the calculation. we want to avoid doing the lookup in the worksheet cells

Comment: Always a good practice. Continuous references back to cells slows everything down.